# multiple rect in an svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

I expect rect is like div where's display block?

```html
<svg width="400" height="180">
  <rect width="150" height="150" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" />
  
    <rect width="150" height="150" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" />

</svg>
```

but it will overlap each other. How to make another rect and wrap it within one svg?

Comment: SVG elements don't wrap.  It's not like HTML. It doesn't automatically lay itself out neatly.  You have to specify exactly where you want the rectangle to be using the `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the x and y [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect#attributes) based on whether you want to align it horizontally or vertically.

Since you had a height of 180 for svg, the vertical positioning might be hidden. You need to increase that too.

**Horizontal positioning**

```html
<svg width="400" height="180">
    <rect width="150" height="150" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" />
    <rect x="200" width="150" height="150" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" />
</svg>
```

**Vertical positioning**

```html
<svg width="400" height="480">
    <rect width="150" height="150" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" />
    <rect y="200" width="150" height="150" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" />
</svg>
```